# Grails unit test on simple controller gets Null pointer Exception

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-2.3

I'm working through the examples in The Definitive Guide to Grails 2, and all the unit testing is different from the version I am using ( 2.3.7).

What I'm trying to do is test that my register method in the UserController will throw an error if the confirmation password, and password field are not the same.  The book gives a test like this

```
void testPasswordsDoNotMatch() {
    request.method = 'POST'

    params.login = 'henry'
    params.password = 'password'
    params.confirm = 'wrongPassword'
    params.firstName = 'Henry'
    params.lastName = 'Rollins'

    def model = controller.register()
    def user = model.user

    assert user.hasErrors()
    assert 'user.password.dontmatch' == user.errors['password'].code
}
```

So obviously that doesn't work, so I put it together like this:

```
    void "test PasswordsDoNotMatch"() {
    given: 
        params.login='henry'
        params.password='password'
        params.confirm='wrongPassword'
        params.firstName='Henry'
        params.lastName='Rollins'

    when:
        def model = controller.register()
        def user = model.user

    then:
         user.hasErrors()
         'user.password.dontmatch' == user.errors['password'].code


}
```

My UserController looks like this:

```
    package com.gtunes

class UserController {


def register() {
    if(request.method =='POST'){
        def u = new User(params)
        u.properties['login', 'password', 'firstName', 'lastName'] = params
        if(u.password != params.confirm){
            u.errors.rejectValue("password", "user.password.dontmatch")
            return [user:u]
        } else if(u.save()) {
            session.user = u
            redirect controller:"store"
        } else {
            return[user:u]
        }

    }


}

}
```

When I run the test using the command grails> test-app  UserController , I get the following error:

> Failure:  |
>   test PasswordsDoNotMatch(com.gtunes.UserControllerSpec)
>   |
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'user' on null object
>          at com.gtunes.UserControllerSpec.test PasswordsDoNotMatch(UserController
>   Spec.groovy:38)

It seems the code I've made doesn't actually create the user in the way I expected, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or the proper way to test this.  I have read through the documentation here:  [Grails testing](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/testing.html#unitTesting), and I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anywhere the request method being set to POST. Try adding `request.method = 'POST'` in the `given` block.

Comment: That was exactly the problem.  Thank you!   
I'm new to posting here (although I've been finding solutions for the past 3 years.)  Should I post the answer or..?

Comment: You can delete the question if you think it does not add value to any other reader. I can add it as an answer but it's too trivial to be added as one. :)

Comment: I suppose I'll leave it as is, simply because if I would have found this question while trying to figure out how to get the testing to work right it would have saved me a fair amount of time.  Thanks again.